# How to run Symfony web server from PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

Is it possible for me to run Symfony web-server from the PhpStorm?
I know I can run it from the command line:

```
php app/console server:run --env=dev
```

I just wonder if there is any way how to configure PhpStorm to do it for me.

Comment: Few possible options: 1) [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality 2) Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Script" type may also work. Possibly there are  other ways as well (e.g. run it via npm/gulp/grunt/phing task or alike)... I'm just not a Symfony user + I prefer using "proper" web server (Apache/nginx/IIS) over PHP's server so cannot think of other ways right now.

Comment: It would be great, if I could even put break-points into my code.

Comment: You may also create an alias using Command Line Tool Integration to quickly run such command. Other than that (in case if you have not seen it yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really see what so special about debugging using such web server. AFAIK nothing changes from normal debugging (if it would be Apache/nginx/whatever). Of course, I might be wrong here (as I do not use such built-in web servers) .. but so far I see nothing special here.

Comment: " I do not really see what so special about debugging using such web server" -- There is nothing special about it. It is just nice to have feature.

Comment: What I mean to say there is: what's so special/different about debugging the web page served by Symfony's web server and the same code served by "proper" web serve like Apache/etc? AFAIK -- nothing.

Comment: It's mainly so you can get something going and tested very quickly without having to do all of the server configuration https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Symfony WebServer Bundle Setup

- Click `Run -> Edit Configurations`
- In the dialog box Click `+` (add)
- Select `PHP Script` from the drop down list
- In the name field type `Symfony Web-Server`
- In the Script field put the path to your `bin/console`
  eg: `/path/to/symfony/bin/console`
- Optionally uncheck `Activate Tool Window` to prevent it from popping up when started
- In the arguments field type `server:run`
- Click Ok to save and close the dialog box

[image: Symfony Web-Server Script]

This will provide you with a `Run Symfony Web-Server` and `Debug Symfony Web-Server` option to select. To debug the running server, you must tell PHPStorm to listen for debug connections prior to running the server script. To configure debugging in your `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers` ensure you have `127.0.0.1:8000` created, disable `Path Mapping` and you have Xdebug set as the debugger. Optionally disable stop at first line in the `Debug -> XDebug` settings.

[image: PHP Server Settings]

Now you can start the server by selecting it in your Run configuration drop down, and clicking the Play button, or by clicking `Run -> Symfony Web-Server`.

Be sure to tell PHPStorm to Listen for Debug connections first.

[image: Debug bar]

Add breakpoints, then launch your browser to a Route affected by the breakpoint(s) and PHPStorm should capture the debug session and break as desired.

[image: debug output]

If debugging fails at first, close all of the running PHPStorm services, and try running the `Debug Symfony Web-Server` (ensuring that PHPStorm is listening for Debug Connections) and then re-launch your browser.
For some reason Xdebug may not initialize otherwise, but this behavior is sporadic and hard to reproduce consistently. After it initializes you can run the non-debug web-server while listening is enabled, and it seems to work fine.

> Special note, running the `Debug Symfony Web-Server` will only monitor
> the bin/console script. This is because the Symfony server php process
> is forked and the debug session will be left monitoring the parent
> process. So you must tell PHPStorm to listen for debug connections
> when debugging the web server.

---

### Symfony CLI setup

The Symfony Web-Server was added to the new [Symfony CLI binary](https://symfony.com/doc/5.0/setup/symfony_server.html). To continue using the Symfony web server as a PHP Script, described above, you must install the [`symfony/web-server-bundle`](https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle) compatible with your version of Symfony.

> The `symfony/web-server-bundle` is depreciated as of Symfony 4.4 and will be removed in Syfmony 5.0

To set up the Symfony CLI web-server in PHPStorm, you can create an [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-third-party-tools.html).

```
Program: symfony 
Arguments: server:start --no-tls
Working Directory: $ProjectFileDir$
```

[image: PHPStorm External Tools]

You can then run the command from your <kbd>Tools</kbd> menu.

[image: PHPStorm symfony server:start]

Or you can execute it from a Run/Debug configuration, similarly to the Symfony WebServer Bundle configuration above, that instead executes the External Tool you created.

[image: PHPStorm symfony server:start configuration]

When running either of the above, you should get a new Run dialog CLI inside PHPStorm.

[image: PHPStorm Run symfony server:start]

> As the Symfony CLI web-server runs outside of the PHP script configuration, it does not suffer the random issues with X-Debug and PHPStorm not listening. I was unable to reproduce the issues in my testing.

However, PHPStorm requires that your server host be changed from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:8000` for the X-Debug path mapping in PHPStorm to work.

If you do not update the host, PHPStorm will prompt you for the configuration when it encounters a break-point, just click <kbd>Accept</kbd> for a new server to be automatically added.

[image: PHPStorm Incoming COnnection from X-Debug]

**Result**

[image: Syfmony 5 server X-Debug]

Comment: As a side note, I highly recommend setting up Docker or Vagrant with your desired OS distribution and flavor of web server (Apache, NginX, IIS). As it is the most consistent means of replicating your production environment and testing on your local system in a similar environment prior to deploying.

Comment: This no longer works with Symfony 5. The only way to do run a server from CLI is through "symfony server:start"

Comment: @Emil You need to install the `syfmony/web-server-bundle`, however the bundle has been depreciated since Symfony 4.4 and is expected to be removed in Symfony 5.0 in favor of using the new Syfmony CLI binary. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @fyrye I've set up everything as you have it above in Symfony 4.4. I am able to launch the server via the PhpStorm Terminal window, but if I try to launch it via the PHP Script route, I am getting an error on 'Reloading PHP Versions' -> no PHP binaries detected. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @mcriecken Ensure you have [specified a PHP interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html) in PHPStorm for the project and/or the script. Which I believe PHPStorm adds to it's console `PATH` when opened. In the images above it is set as the default interpreter of my project. Otherwise make sure your php.exe directory is specified in your `PATH` System Environment Variable, which will execute `php <command>` by loading php.exe from the specified `PATH`, which the symfony CLI may be attempting to find.

Comment: Thanks, @fyrye. I made a mistake above - I actually have Symfony 5 installed, not 4.4 as I mentioned. I think the issue has something to do with the WSL setup I'm trying to configure properly. I've been able to set up debugging properly, I just can't seem to get PHPStorm to launch the Symfony server (except for manually typing it into the PHPStorm Terminal).

Comment: @mcriecken Windows Subsystem for Linux is very much so a different environment. I would suggest using a Remote SSH External Tool instead of the standard External Tools. A bit surprised the Symfony CLI would work under the general Terminal window in PHPStorm and not an SSH terminal as well. I abandoned using WSL personally in favor of using Vagrant + VirtualBox, there were too many inconsistencies and issues trying to bridge PHPStorm with WSL.

Comment: @fyrye Thanks for the recommendation. I'm going to try out Vagrant + VirtualBox and see how that goes. I watched a short tutorial and it looks much more straightforward than WSL.

Answer (score 2):

To setup Symfony CLI on Windows you can use Bash template:

1. Click `Run -> Edit Configurations`
2. In the dialog box Click `+` (add)
3. Select `Bash` from the drop down list
4. In the name field type `Symfony server`
5. In the Script field type `serve`
6. In the Interpreter path field put the path to your command console eg: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
7. In the Interpreter options field type `/k "symfony"`
8. In the Program arguments field type `--no-tls`

Click Ok to save and close the dialog box

[Edit Configurations dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hi1S.png)

Now you can start and stop Symfony server from the top panel:

[Run Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP2qQ.png)

Comment: I am trying to do the same in Linux but you have to enter full Script Path and if I enter `/usr/local/bin/symfony` it doesn't work. Any ideas?